# Loading an older version SWF by a newer version SWF

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex3

I have  an Action Script project made with Flash Builder 4.7 and the AIR SDK 3.7. I want to load the swf that is packaged inside an AIR file created with Flash Builder 4 and the Flex SDK 3.5. I managed but its scaled about 300% and its shifted to the right too leaving a huge white border on its left side.

I read the following in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-7fff:

When loading a SWF file of a different version than the loading content, you can run into the two problems:

-Loading a newer version SWF by an older version SWF— References to APIs added in the newer versions of AIR and Flash Player in the loaded content will be unresolved

-Loading an older version SWF by a newer version SWF — APIs changed in the newer versions of AIR and Flash Player may behave in ways that the loaded content does not expect.

I think the second is my case. My initial problem is described in http://mabulous.com/de/air-applications-that-can-be-updated-without-requiring-admin-rights and the solution worked for me only to lead to this new problem. Any ideas please?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0c.html did you check this?

Comment: Was a problem with the stage I changed: stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
   stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
   stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; Now It works